# QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I'm working in a Python application that have to launch multiples windows. 
The soft works, but the cmd is spammed by lines:

- "QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to splash_direction_App "", which already has a layout"
- "QLayout::addChildLayout: layout "" already has a parent"

by searching on the internet, i found that's an issue with my inheritance définition, especially with the layout ones. 
but i can''t manage to resolve the issue.

```
class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """ Process de connexion au logiciel de ticketing"""

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("tests")   
        self.resize(400,200)
        self.move(1500,100)
        self.setup_Main_UI()
        self.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt;")

#####Mise en forme de la fenetre de connexion        
    def setup_Main_UI(self):
        self.log_layout=QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.log_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        #main label
        self.log_Title=QtWidgets.QLabel("Identification")
        self.log_Title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.log_Title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.log_Title.setStyleSheet("font: bold;")

        self.log_Title_spacer_layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.log_Title_spacer=QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.log_Title_spacer_layout.addSpacerItem(self.log_Title_spacer)
        #button Admin

        self.identifiant_label=QtWidgets.QLabel("Identifiant")
        self.identifiant_Entry=QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)

        self.mdp_label=QtWidgets.QLabel("Mot de passe")
        self.mdp_Entry=QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.mdp_Entry.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        self.error_label=QtWidgets.QLabel("")

        self.log_button=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Connexion")
        self.log_button.clicked.connect(self.log_ID)

        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.log_Title,0,0)
        self.log_layout.addLayout(self.log_Title_spacer_layout,1,0)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.identifiant_label,2,0)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.identifiant_Entry,2,1)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.mdp_label, 3,0)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.mdp_Entry, 3,1)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.error_label,5,1)
        self.log_layout.addWidget(self.log_button, 7,1)

    def log_ID (self):
        """ Analyse de l'identifiant et mdp, puis lancement du bon interface utilisateur Utilisateur/administrateur/direction"""
        self.identifiant=self.identifiant_Entry.text()
        self.mdp=self.mdp_Entry.text()
        verrouille=True
        while  verrouille :
            logging_value=(self.identifiant,[self.mdp])
            if logging_value in super_user.items():
                self.splash_App_launch()
                self.close()
                verrouille=False

    def splash_App_launch(self):
        """Lance la fenêtre de choix de connexion admin en cas de clic sur le bouton
        """
        # crée la 2ème fenêtre
        self.splash_App = splash_App()
        # rend modale la 2ème fenêtre (la 1ère fenêtre sera inactive)
        self.splash_App.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        # affiche la 2ème fenêtre
        self.splash_App.show()
        self.close()

class splash_App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Fenetre de choix pour les utilisateurs ayant plsueirs accès"""
    def __init__(self):

        super(splash_App,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Mails service carte expert")   
        self.resize(400,200)
        self.move(1500,100)
        self.setStyleSheet("font: 10pt;")
        self.main_layout=QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        #main label
        self.main_Title=QtWidgets.QLabel("Outils de ticketing mails Carte Expert")
        self.main_Title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.main_Title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.main_Title.setStyleSheet("font: bold;")

        #button Admin
        self.Admin_Layout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.Admin_Button=QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self)
        self.Admin_Button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64,64))
        self.Admin_Button.setMaximumWidth(64)
        self.Admin_spacer=QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.Admin_label=QtWidgets.QLabel("Accès Administrateur")

        self.Admin_Button.clicked.connect(self.close_open_UI_admin)

        self.Admin_Layout.addWidget(self.Admin_Button)
        self.Admin_Layout.addSpacerItem(self.Admin_spacer)
        self.Admin_Layout.addWidget(self.Admin_label)

        #spacers
        self.Title_spacer=QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0,0,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.icones_spacer=QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(50,50,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        #button Utilisateur
        self.User_Layout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.User_Button=QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self)
        self.User_Button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(64,64))
        self.User_Button.setMaximumWidth(64)        
        self.User_label=QtWidgets.QLabel("Accès Utilisateur")
        self.User_spacer=QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20,20,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self.User_Button.clicked.connect(self.close_open_UI_user)

        self.User_Layout.addWidget(self.User_Button)   
        self.User_Layout.addSpacerItem(self.User_spacer)
        self.User_Layout.addWidget(self.User_label)        

        self.Glob_icon_layout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Glob_icon_layout.addLayout(self.User_Layout)
        self.Glob_icon_layout.addSpacerItem(self.icones_spacer)
        self.Glob_icon_layout.addLayout(self.Admin_Layout)

        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.main_Title,1,0)
        self.main_layout.setVerticalSpacing(50)

        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.Glob_icon_layout,3,0)

    def close_open_UI_admin(self):
        """ferme la fenetre et lance l'environnement choisi"""
        self.UI_admin=Ui_Admin_livrable.App_Admin()
        self.UI_admin.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.UI_admin.show()
        self.close()      

    def close_open_UI_user(self):
        """ferme la fenetre et lance l'environnement choisi"""
        self.UI_user=Ui_User_livrable.App_User()
        self.UI_user.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.UI_user.show()
        self.close()
```

Comment: change to `self.Admin_Layout=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()`

Comment: Thank you ! I just have to manage with the parent message and everything will be ok.